# How to overload operator in Parsec/Megaparsec?

Tags: haskell, parsec, megaparsec

I am implementing a compiler using [Parsec/Megaparsec as parser](https://jakewheat.github.io/intro_to_parsing/). I can't find a way to overload operator `+`, which I want to use for both integer addition and string concatenation. Is it possible?

Comment: It's possible, but it needs *far* more information than you've provided. Can you ask a concrete question? Something along the lines of "this is a small self-contained representative of the code I'm having trouble with, these are the exact problems I'm having."

Comment: You could parse raw syntax & have a typechecking phase afterwards.

Comment: One simple way to do it is to make String an instance of the Num class and define the class method (+) to be (++). But then the compiler will expect implementations of all the methods of Num. Also a quick test showed that you need to turn on 'Flexible Instances'. I'm not an expert, but it feels very unnatural to me.

Answer (score 1):

Start by writing your compiler to use a different operator for string concatenation, like `@`.  When you've got it running and well tested, take a look at your code.  You'll probably discover that one of two things has happened, depending on the language you're parsing and the compiler architecture you've used.

The **first** possibility is that the part of your parser that parses `+` is completely separate from the part of the parser that parses `@` (e.g., they are in two different parser functions, one for parsing numeric expressions and a separate one for parsing string expressions).  If this has happened, congratulations, you just need to replace `"@"` with `"+"`, run a few tests, and you should be good to go.

The **second** possibility is that `+` and `@` are parsed in the same place and produce AST nodes with different constructors:

```
data Expr ... =
  ...
  | Plus Expr Expr     -- the '+' operator
  | Concat Expr Expr   -- the '@' operator
  ...
```

In this case, you probably also have some part of your compiler that's generating code (and hopefully some type information):

```
codeGen (Plus e1 e2)
  = do (code1, typ1) <- codeGen e1
       (code2, typ2) <- codeGen e2
       if (typ1 == Num && typ2 == Num)
         then genPlus code1 code2
         else typeError "'+' needs numbers"
codeGen (Concat e1 e2)
  = do (code1, typ1) <- codeGen e1
       (code2, typ2) <- codeGen e2
       if (typ1 == Str && typ2 == Str)
         then genConcat code1 code2
         else typeError "'@' needs strings"
```

In this case, you should modify the parser/AST to collapse the AST to just one shared constructor:

```
data Expr ... =
  ...
  | ConcatPlus Expr Expr     -- the '+' operator for numbers and strings
  ...
```

and handle both cases in the code generator, depending on available type information:

```
codeGen (ConcatPlus e1 e2)
  = do (code1, typ1) <- codeGen e1
       (code2, typ2) <- codeGen e2
       case (typ1, typ2) of
           (Num, Num) -> genPlus code1 code2
           (Str, Str) -> genConcat code1 code2
           _ -> typeError "'+' arguments must have same type (numbers or strings)"
```

If your compiler doesn't look like these examples, you'll have to post some code so we know what it **does** look like.